# SSL on dockerize nginx server

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx

I have some issues to put a selfsigned SSL/TLS certificated on my dockerize nginx server.
Here is my nginx.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 ssl;
    server_name  localhost;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key;
    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}
```

And here is my Dockerfile

```
#==================== Building Stage ================================================

# Create the image based on the official Node 8.9.0 image from Dockerhub

FROM node:8.9.0 as node

# Create a directory where our app will be placed. This might not be necessary

RUN mkdir -p /to-do-app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory

WORKDIR /to-do-app

# Copy dependency definitions

COPY package.json /to-do-app

# Install dependencies using npm

RUN npm install

# Get all the code needed to run the app

COPY . /to-do-app
COPY certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt /etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt
COPY certs/nginx-selfsigned.key /etc/ssl/private/nginx-selfsigned.key
COPY nginx-to-do-app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default-ssl.conf

# Expose the port the app runs in

EXPOSE 4200

#Build the app

RUN npm run build

#==================== Setting up stage ====================

# Create image based on the official nginx - Alpine image

FROM nginx:1.13.7-alpine

COPY --from=node /to-do-app/dist/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx-to-do-app.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

I can successfully create an image with

```
docker build . -t myimage
```

But if I try to create the container with

```
docker run -p 80:80 myimage
```

I encounter the following error

```
2018/07/05 14:08:05 [emerg] 1#1: BIO_new_file("/etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
nginx: [emerg] BIO_new_file("/etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt") failed (SSL: error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:fopen('/etc/ssl/certs/nginx-selfsigned.crt','r') error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file)
```

I'm on windows 10 using powershell (but have the same error with git bash) with Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40